# Threading view in chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

Could a threading view be implemented? I.e. I click on Marc's message to indicate I reply to that thread? And if someone else doesn't care about that, he can just unwrap it while following other ideas. I don't think this is something that requires separate rooms though

Comment: I mean as *option*. No need to down-vote just because you don't *need* it

Comment: Like Google Wave? <shudder>

Comment: @Robert Cartaino♦: I must admit I never had a look at it... But if it caused trauma, I'll retreat the request...

Comment: I suspect Google Wave will be the Workplace Shell of communication systems... Others grabbing bits and pieces for years to come but never fully grasping the underlying vision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never seen this concept on chat. I expect all new chat messages to appear at the end of the list. A 'threading' feature would allow active conversations in 'older' parts of the message area, it would be just impossible to see and follow all active discussions.

Example to illustrate: two threaded discussion start at a distance(?) of one hour and you want to follow both - I don't see a chance to have both conversations on a screnn with some hundred other messages between them. (Hope it's understandable..)

Comment: It's rather like "I don't care about the ice-cream discussion, so let me hide it" without hiding anything the users say on other topics. And maybe different colouration for different threads

Comment: @Tobias - that, in fact, sounds like a good idea. But I doubt, that icecream trolls really respond to a thread, knowing that they can easily be ignored that way ;) ('Good idea' was written before the different color addition...)

Comment: The colour addition would be a mechanism to lure trolls into using the threading - trolls like shiny things. Plus it would help viewing those answers that *are* threaded