# Ability to create "group of lines of chat"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, reference

I imagine in the future there will be a lot of comments on questions in the form of *as discussed in the chat, this and that*.

I think it would be useful to link to the relevant part of that chat, so I'd like the ability to create a named list of lines of chat and link to it.

#### For example:

- I think we should close question X. `click`
- Why?
- It's subjective and not suitable for a Q&A site. `click`
- waffles waffles waffles
- I agree, there's not a single answer to that question! `click`
- We all agree! Also, unicorns are pretty!
- Agreed. `click`

All clicked lines would be saved from the transcript with a dedicated url, for reference.

Comment: This would be very useful where you want to quote something *and* respond.

Comment: So my [threading view suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57024/threading-view-in-chat) wouldn't be so bad after all? That would help creating the appropriate transcript

Comment: We'll definitely *consider* this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/waiting-for-the-200000th-message

Answer (score 2):

First off, I love this idea.

One thing major that needs to be considered. If we (they) are going to create a dynamic amended transcript for linking, there should be a visual indication that you have skipped some lines.

> **Devin**: We should have an admin password that can log in as other people. I'll keep it on a post-it attached to my monitor.
>   **Juan**: That's foolish, ridiculous and unsafe.
>   **Marc**: It would be better to  < insert magical architecture that solves problem >.
>   **Juan**: Great Idea!

I could link this chat

> **Devin**: We should have an admin password that can log in securely as other people. I'll keep it on a post-it attached to my monitor.
>   **Juan**: Great Idea!

If however, we use some syntax like "[...]" or the pencil icon (like on comments) to indicate that the chatlog has some lines removed, that would prevent this problem.

Comment: I don't talk like that

Comment: That's pretty much the same thing people were worried about when comment voting came along. (Edit: In reply to devinb, not Juan Manuel -- funny as that would be.)

Comment: That doesn't really "prevent" the problem. There's no knowing that the [...] is just unnecessary noise versus removing actual relevant portions.

Comment: @Grace, the pencil icon after the edited comment only indicates that it *was* edited, not *how*. But it's good enough. Also, if there were an accessible general chat log, then you could verify against source if you felt like it.

Comment: @Juan maybe you could edit it to be more... forceful. I figured that trying to adequately talk like you would be even more insulting.

Comment: @mmyers Do you mean comment editing? If you do, that's why I specifically mentioned the 'edited' pencil icon. It simply means that the history may have been altered somewhat.

Comment: @devinb: I do remember the concerns about editing, but I thought there was also something about only seeing part of the conversation in the unexpanded page when several comments are upvoted. Can't find it now.

Comment: @mmyers I thought that could've been what you meant, but occam's razor implied the other option. My response to *that* concern is that I was explicity concerned about that when I first saw that functionality. (Unsurprisingly, I wrote at length about it), however that one is less controllable than this. If I want to "game" that system, it requires that no one else upvotes comments without my direction. With *this* issue, I am completely in control of what the conversation looks like.

Comment: The implentation we went with only allows for a linear conversation to be bookmarked (i.e. you can't leave out messages).

Answer (score 1):

Just as an update, we now have the core of this, as an off-shoot to some of the moderation controls (to block-delete, or drag some parts of a conversation to a new room).

We haven't added anything extra re quoting etc, but it is certainly now feasible.