# What ways exist to group messages in chat?

Tags: feature-request, support, chat

I would like to know if it is possible to group several messages in chat, so they can be replied to together.

Example:

> **Foo_user:** I had a walk in the park today and found a really nice place under some trees.
>   **Foo_user:** I wonder if we could have a barbecue there.
>   [...]
>   **Bar_user:** @Foo_user this is a really good idea.

A more complicated case:

> **Foo_user:** I had a walk in the park today and found a really nice place under some trees.
>   ***Alien_user:*** I had an awful day at the dentist.
>   **Foo_user:** I wonder if we could have a barbecue there.
>   [...]
>   **Bar_user:** @Foo_user this is a really good idea.

It would be nice if *Bar_user's* reply could highlight both of *Foo_user's* messages together. Is there a way for *Bar_user* to do this?

Is there a way for *Foo_user* to group his/her two messages together to ensure replies like *Bar_user's* would refer to both parts of his/her proposal?

If this is not possible, are there other means for *Foo_user* or *Bar_user* to maintain a visible context to their discussion, short of creating a dedicated chat room?

Comment: You could permalink them. *[this](link) and [that](link) are really good idea's*

Comment: You can create bookmarked conversations but that doesn't help with replying as such and is for larger conversations that just a couple of messages but you can refer to them in links for reference.

Comment: @Jon Yes, I've already [played in the sandbox with what you are suggesting](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/conversation/flint-sandbox-example). I would be chuffed if it turned out there was a more elegant way to do this; as you said `this doesn't help with replying as such` and, [for a good reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57394/ability-to-create-group-of-lines-of-chat/58123#58123), you wouldn't be able to edit out *Alien_user's* message.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You can basically only reply to one message - and the 'underlying' shortcut kinda refers to the message.

SE chat modifications shows the message ID so you can see this in my screenshot. In addition, as far as I recall, there's also a thumbnail of a message that's been responded to, and that would need fixing. You'd need a fair amount of changes to get what you want.

[image]

So, as is, there's no more elegant way than the standard, ping-pong conversation and replies are at best, in a one to many relation, rather than a many to one relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can group messages together by creating a chat bookmark, then link to it and ping the user you want, asking for their attention.

To create a chat bookmark:

1. Click the "room" link in the right sidebar below the room description and tags:

   > [image]
2. In the menu which opens, click "create new bookmark":

   > [image]
3. Click the first then the last messages you want to group together, e.g.

   > [image]

   Note: can only select range, can't select specific messages.
4. Give it a name and click "bookmark":

   > [image]
5. You'll get a notification with a link to the new bookmark:

   > [image]

Now you can post the URL of the bookmark, which will onebox it, and ping the user you want to get reply from:

> [image]